# Constrain text to a location, then have it dynamically move if required

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am making a `UITableView` with two labels. I have constrained the `secondLabel` to be +12 from the `firstLabel`, meaning it will move *along* if the `firstLabel` contains a lot of text. However, that means if the `firstLabel` contains hardly any text the `secondLabel` will move *back*. What can I do to make this work?

I would like to have it react like this:

`secondLabel` stays in place despite there being very little text in the `firstLabel`:

```
_________________________________________________________
|                                                        |
|  [abc]        [secondLabel]                            |
|________________________________________________________|
```

`secondLabel` moves along due to `firstLabel` having a lot of text to display:

```
__________________________________________________________
|                                                        |
|  [extralongfirstLabel] [secondLabel]                   |
|________________________________________________________|
```

Both the `firstLabel` and `secondLabel` will have a varying amount of text. The `firstLabel` leading side should be constrained to the SuperView margin. 
The `secondLabel` would maintain a distance of 12 from the leading side of the firstLabel, but then remain 56.5 from the SuperView when not constraining to the firstLabel (when it contains little text).

Both text labels are on the left of the cell, allowing the text to spread across it.

I am trying to complete this task via the IB, but if you have any code suggestions please let me know.

Comment: What are your requirements for the placement of the second label? Does its amount of text change? Do you want it to be a variable distance from the trailing side of the cell? What are the parameters for the leading edge of the second label?

Comment: Both the firstLabel and secondLabel will have a varying amount of text. The firstLabel leading side should be constrained to the SuperView margin. I would like . the secondLabel to maintain a distance of 12 from the leading side of the firstLabel, but then remain 56.5 from the SuperView when not constraining to the firstLabel (when it contains little text).  Both text labels are on the left of the cell, allowing the text to spread across it. The diagrams I created above make it appear as if they're centred in the cell.

Comment: give first label width of say 70 and set priority to 999  or only >=70 ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan this only half works, because even though the secondLabel maintains a distance, the firstLabel is cut short with `...`

Comment: sure you followed correctly ? , then set horizontal compression to 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like job for multiple constraints, one of which has a lower priority.

First, a required (priority 1000) greater-than-or-equal-to constraint to space the second label's leading edge 12 points from the first label's trailing edge.

Second, a lower-priority constraint for the distance between the cell's and the second label's leading edges. This will be broken when the first label becomes too large, which is fine: that's why it's lower priority.

When the second constraint is broken, the first constraint will be the control for the distance between the labels.

Answer (score 1):

So, for first label set its leading constraint equal to superview's with constant how you want to.

Now, for second label set two leading constraints.

1. One equal to first label's trailing constraint with some static
   constant (means relation **equal**) and with lower priority (set its priority lower than for the second leading constraint, so for example 999)

   [image]
2. Second equal to superview's leading constraint with
       relation **greater than or equal**

[image]

Constraints:

[image]

---

Result:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to change the priority on one of the constraints or they conflict when the first label is small.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm not sure what you mean, in which case? I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: E.g. the first label's leading edge is 8 from the cell's leading edge, and the width of the first label is 100. So its trailing edge is at 108. The second label's leading edge is now supposed to be both at 128 (because of the constraint to the first label) AND 200 (because of the constraint to the cell). This is a contradiction.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're right (ofc), I'd tested it wrong. Thank you! :)